# Правильно ли поставлено двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Наш стратегический вектор остается неизменным: мы стремимся к технологическому и инновационному лидерству в отрасли, постоянно работаем над качеством своей продукции, развиваем стратегическое сотрудничество с лидерами мировой уплотнительной техники.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно. Одно из немногих синтаксически некорявых предложений. )))